# UIRefreshControl hangs indefinitely

Tags: iphone, ios, asynchronous, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UIRefreshControl, and it works fine when you use it, but it hangs, it never goes away. I've tried

```
[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
```

This solution was from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387378/uirefreshcontrol-uitableview-stuck-while-refreshing?rq=1), but it has not addressed mine.

Even with this, the refreshControl continues spinning, not dismissing. Why is this?

In my viewDidLoad:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(refreshFeed) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

[refreshControl addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(refreshFeed)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

refreshFeed method...

```
-(void)refreshFeed
//load those feeds
{
RSSLoader* rss = [[RSSLoader alloc] init];    
[rss fetchRssWithURL:feedURL
            complete:^(NSString *title, NSArray *results) {
                dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader",NULL);
                dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

                _objects = results;

                //completed fetching the RSS
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                });
                });
                }];
}
```

Comment: does the tableView reloadData work? if not, make it run on the main thread

Comment: reloadData does work... If I put that method anywhere else the cells do not load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try changing this line

```
[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

with

```
[self setRefreshControl:refreshControl];
```